# Bootstrap Tooltip triggers class alert?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I get a strange background when I enable a tooltip. It might be the alert class, but I tried to delete it and it didn't help. Here's a picture:

[image]

HTML:

```
<a href="#Top" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="Upp"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-up"></i></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
        $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! At this point I think your question needs to provide more context.  What additional CSS is being applied to the anchor? Is that element a direct child of the body, or are there parent elements which might be relevant? A great way to share a problem is to recreate the identical problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: On a separate note, the `if` statement is unnecessary.  E.g., calling `$([]).tooltip()` won't throw any errors.

Comment: Not quite confident enough to post this as an answer, but Bootstrap's documentation is pretty solid. Here's the article on tooltip(). http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I found the problem when I inserted the code on fiddle website, I will use the bootstrap on a Joomla site, apparently so was my css overrided by system.css though I load it before my code.

I did not see the system code CSS in Google Chrome console either, maybe because I load them with php?

Comment: require ('.. /.. /.. / media / system / css / system.css');
require ('.. /.. / system / css / system.css');
require ('.. /.. / system / css / general.css');
require ('bootstrap.css');
require ('template.css');
require ('font-awesome.css');
require ('bootstrap responsive.css');

Strange that no one else has had the problem, maybe not so many people use the bootstrap with Joomla: P

Thanks for the help anyway.